# Keyword not supported: @microsoft.keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I was trying to get the connection string from the azure key vault for azure functions. These are the steps I did,

1. Created a managed identity(System assigned) in the azure functions
2. Create a secret in an azure key vault
3. Add access policies to give permission to the azure function app
4. Added an entry in the app settings for connection string where the value was @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=SECRETURLOFKEYVAULT)

But when I run the azure function I am getting below error,

"Keyword not supported: @microsoft.keyvault(secreturi....."

This is how I have enabled managed identity,

[image]

And my access policy looks like below,

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you confirm that the access policy is against the managed identity and that you did not configure the "authorized application" section of the policy?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem by following the tutorial. My remedy was a restart of the function app. Saving of the app setting was not enough for the Function App to start using the Key Vault secret provider correctly.

Comment: I had a similar issue but had to restart the entire App Service for it to take effect. Saving nor refreshing has no effect at all in fetching new values. Even witnessed that `SecretUri` without version doesn't fetch the latest. I even disable the previous but nothing happened.

Comment: Having same problem randomly. The app restart fixes the issue but it is super annoying.

Comment: This is super annoying. If I run my IaC bicep deployment, then it effectively takes down my app because the connection string to the DB no longer resolves!

Answer (score 1):

According to the steps you provided, it have no problem to work well. Here is the [tutorial](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b) about get key vault secrets in Azure Function you could refer to.

**Note**: Add access policies to the azure function app **with the `Get` permission on secrets and that was enough**.

Also, here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23250) that get same error like you which is due to `IP Address restriction blocking it`.

Comment: My policy is set to GET only as you can see in the edited question but still, it is not working.

Comment: Have you check the tutorial I provided? I test in my site and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred while testing on local. It was resolved after doing an `az login`.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was due to the App Service not having permissions to that KeyVault item. The App Service App Settings does give a visible warning (a red cross on the setting) if it can't access it - so that helped us diagnose.